# ORM django , filtre by object.proprety

Tags: python, django, orm

I have problem getting result from this view :

```
    def bultinPaie(request, id, cin) :
        employe = Employe.objects.get(id = id)
        listSalaire = Salaire.objects.filter(employe.cin == cin)

    return render(request, 'backEnd/bultinPaie.html.html', {'listSalaire' : listSalaire})
```

i know employe.cin isn't valid because it's not a proprety of Salaire classe .

Here is a the models im using

```
class Employe(models.Model):
    matricule = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    nom = models.TextField()
    prenom = models.TextField()
    cin = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    telephone = models.TextField(max_length=10)
    adresse = models.TextField()
    grade = models.TextField()
    dateEmbauche = models.DateField()

class Salaire (models.Model):
    employe = models.ForeignKey(Employe,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    montant = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    mois = models.TextField()
    annee = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def bultinPaie(request, id, cin):
    employe = get_object_or_404(Employe, id=id)
    listSalaire = Salaire.objects.filter(employe__cin=cin)
    return render(request, ‘backEnd/bultinPaie.html.html', {'listSalaire' : listSalaire})
```

Here however one determine the `Salaire`s based on another parameter. As a result, a person can visit a URL with a different `cin` and thus access somebody else `Salaire`.

You might want to filter with:

```
def bultinPaie(request, id, cin):
    listSalaire = Salaire.objects.filter(employe__id=id, employe__cin=cin)
    return render(request, ‘backEnd/bultinPaie.html.html', {'listSalaire' : listSalaire})
```